# Suppose that two vectors u and v in R^n are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

i.e. span a subspace of dimension two (a plane) P. Show that a vector w that is perpendicular to both u and v is perpendicular to each vector in P.

Proof:
If V is a subspace of R^n and S is an orthogonal set which spans V, S is a basis for subspace V, then S is called an orthogonal basis for V. Two vectors x and y are said to be orthogonal if their dot product is zero.

May I get a verification on the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

How we can write a vector $x$ of $V=\mathrm{span}(u,v)$? Calculate $w\cdot x$.

Comment: We know span is c1s1 + c2s2 +... + cnsn | c1,...,cn is an element of the set of real numbers and s1,..,sn is an
element of a nonempty subset S of a vector space
where c1,c2, ...cn is the cofficients of the system

Comment: w * x would be w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ...+wn*xn

Comment: If $x\in\mathrm{span}(u,v)$ then $x=\alpha u+\beta v$ hence $w\cdot x= w\cdot(\alpha u+\beta v)=\alpha w\cdot u+\beta w\cdot v=0$

Comment: okay so w * x shows me the dot product is zero

Comment: your guidance helped me Sami.

Comment: You're welcome, this makes me happy.